# Postgres join JSON list

Tags: json, postgresql, join

I'm having problems joining a JSON list in postgres 9.4

Here's my problem:

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  player json,
  CONSTRAINT players_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE matches
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  match json,
  CONSTRAINT matches_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Sample Data:

```
players
1;"{"Name":"AAA","Height":186,"Weight":65}"
2;"{"Name":"BBB","Height":195,"Weight":85}"
3;"{"Name":"CCC","Height":175,"Weight":72}"
4;"{"Name":"DDD","Height":168,"Weight":56}"

matches
5;{"Id":1,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}
6;{"Id":2,"Teams":[{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]},{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}],"TeamRank":[1,2]}
```

The players on each team are the players that were on the team in that team's last game. A query for getting the team name and a list of players (the current team) is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.team->>'Name') t.team
FROM   matches m, json_array_elements(m.match->'Teams') t(team)
ORDER  BY t.team->>'Name', m.id DESC
```

This returns the following (Teams table):

```
"{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC"},{"Name":"BBB"}]}"
"{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA"},{"Name":"DDD"}]}"
```

I want to join each player in the above result with their height and weight in the list so that the output is the following:

```
"{"Name":"TeamA","Players":[{"Name":"CCC","Height":175,"Weight":72},{"Name":"BBB","Height":195,"Weight":85}]}"
"{"Name":"TeamB","Players":[{"Name":"AAA","Height":186,"Weight":65},{"Name":"DDD","Height":168,"Weight":56}]}"
```

I have tried to do this using an INNER JOIN:

```
WITH u AS (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.team->>'Name') t.team
FROM   matches m, json_array_elements(m.match->'Teams') t(team)   -- FROM ABOVE!!!
ORDER  BY t.team->>'Name', m.id DESC) 

SELECT player FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(team->'Players') FROM u) AS v
INNER JOIN players on v->>'Name'=player->>'Name';
```

This is a step towards what I want, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: record ->> unknown
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 2822
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem or another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
(SELECT json_array_elements(team->'Players') FROM u) AS v
```

declares `v` as a relation, so any references to `v` elsewhere will mean "a record in this relation". So this:

```
v->>'Name'=player->>'Name'
```

doesn't work, because it's trying to use `v` as a JSON value instead of as a record.

To fix this, you need to use a column alias; for example, you could write:

```
SELECT player FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(team->'Players') FROM u) AS v(v_player)
INNER JOIN players on v_player->>'Name' = player->>'Name';
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot. Is Inner Join the best way to do this?

Comment: I still need to get it into the output above, how can I join this back with my previous query?